# MySQL show all lines except those with special character

Tags: mysql, character, line

I have a table with following fields as example. I'm wondering how to ignore some lines WHERE the info has special character or is empty.
Table1 with fields Username   NumberID   CodeUser:

```
Username  NumID    CodeUser 
user1     12345    2454
user2     1452T    /500
user3     45172 
user4     3145Z    /076
```

For this example I would only have lines user1 and user4 and ignore WHERE CodeUser is Empty or has character starting with "/"

```
SELECT * FROM `Table1` 
WHERE CodeUser IS NOT NULL AND CodeUser != /xyz;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
 SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE CodeUser >'' AND CodeUser NOT LIKE '/%';
```

It will ignore both NULL and empty ('') CodeUsers, as well as those starting with "/".